# setInterval an image function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I've got this code that makes a fadein and fadeout effects to black while it changes a randomly generated image:

```
var imgs = new Array("https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/1.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/2.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/3.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/4.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/5.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/6.jpg");

function changeOverlay() {
    $('#overlay').animate({opacity: 1,}, 1000);
    $('#overlay').animate({opacity: 0,}, 1000);
}

setTimeout(
  function changeBg() {
    var imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
  }, 3000);

function changeBackgroundSmoothly() {
    $('#masthead').animate(0, changeBg);
}

setInterval(changeOverlay,2000);
setInterval(changeBackgroundSmoothly,2000);
```

The problem is, the image only rotates the first time, how can I make it looping like the `#overlay`?

You can have a visual idea over here: https://store.vtxfactory.org

Thanks.

Comment: What you really need to do is learn how to debug JavaScript code. Just by opening the console you would see the error Rama mentioned. The debugger lets you step through your code or put logging statements in it and see what what the code is doing. For a start, here is a [guide to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Answer (score 0):

You can see reference Error in the console.

Change the setTimeout method first

```
var changeBg = function() {
    var imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
}

setTimeout(changeBg, 3000);
```